# Pycharm freezes when opening existing or creating new projects

Tags: pycharm

I started having this problem 2 days ago on Mac. I am using Community Edition 2021.2.  When I try to open a new project or an existing project PyCharm hangs and then I need to Force Quit it. I tried removing it completely and removing its folders in Library. Even with a fresh install, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the 2021.1 version which works fine so I am not sure if it was something that was wrong with the 2021.2 version. I will try updating again in a few months to see if it happens again